# How to create a Navigation based application without a uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a Navigation based application and as you most likely know the rootviewcontroller has a uitableview in it.. I would like to change this so its just a standard uiview however everything I have tried so far keeps giving me errors, so I am wondering if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you create navigation based application and then delete TableView from rootViewController.xib and take it view from library and connect it and more thing is that to insert uiviewcontroller instead of uitableview in rootviewcontoller.h file and build & run your project its work fine.

Comment: Okay I will look at this, I have tried it but I was hoping to also clean up all the crap that is in the RootViewController.m file that is automatically put in there.. will give it ago now, thanks for all the answers.

Comment: yep works for me also, the major thing I think I was doing wrong yesterday was not linking the view to the view object

Answer (score 2):

@interface YourController : UIViewController

and replace tableview with UIView and connect it with files owner.. and remove delegate and datasource methods for UItableView.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any UIViewController (even with a plain UIView, no table view) inside a UINavigationController. You can even do this simply by dragging a UIViewController into the tab bar in your interface file. If you post more information about the errors you're seeing, we can help debug further.

Comment: just a heads up you have to use the "view" object not the view controller otherwise you loose your navigation controller.